# How to add 'import-mappings' in the config.yaml file for OpenAPI Generator?

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I am trying to add `import-mappings` to my config file. If I add it to openapi-generator-cli, it works. But I have a bunch of files, so wanted to add this map in my config file.

Here is my config file example (kotlin-config.yaml):

```yaml
generatorName: kotlin
import-mappings:
  MyObject: com.example.sdk.model.MyObject
additionalProperties:
  serializationLibrary: gson
  enumPropertyNaming: UPPERCASE
  library: jvm-volley
  sortParamsByRequiredFlag: false
  parcelizeModels: true
  artifactory_publish: true
  modelMutable: true
```

Here is my CLI command:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate --global-property models,supportingFiles --skip-validate-spec \
                -i ${inputSpec} \
                -c ${configSpec} \
                -o ${artifactDir} \
                -t ${templateDir} \
                -p apiPackage='${groupId}.api',modelPackage='${groupId}.model',groupId='${groupId}',artifactId='${artifactId}',artifactVersion='${buildVersion}'
```

where `configSpec` is the path to the `kotlin-config.yaml` file mentioned above. I tried putting it in brackets; tried putting in ""; also tried = instead of ':' but nothing worked. If I hardcode it in my openapi-generator-cli command, it works. Not sure what I am missing.

Also, is it possible to tell it not to add files for the file in import-mappings? For 'not to add "com.example.sdk.model.MyObject" related imports I added in the `.openapi-generator-ignore` file, but failed. Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. It is supposed to be `importMappings` instead of `import-mappings`.

```yaml
importMappings:
  MyObject: com.example.sdk.model.MyObject
```